# Estoy teniendo problemas para instalar Typescript en mi pc

Tags: typescript

Buen día, estoy siguiendo un curso de Typescript, pero tengo este problema, he visto muchas soluciones en la web como limpiar caché, instalando y desinstalando npm, node pero no logro solucionar, acudo a ustedes para que me de una guía de como solucionar este problema.

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\npm'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Martin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-12T04_02_23_511Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Pues ahí dice que no tienes permisos. O corres eso desde una terminal como admin (idea fea) o cambias la ruta donde se guarda la configuración a algo fuera del AppData del usuario `npm config set prefix C:/carpeta/fuera/misdocumentos/`

Comment: Prueba a desinstalarlo si lo está y reinstalarlo en otro lugar.